# Adding objects to vector results in "does not have class type exception"

Tags: c++

The following code throws the aforementioned error message at the line where an object is added to a vector:

```
include "palm.h"
include <vector>

using namespace std;

class forehead {
  public:
    void palmstrikesforehead(float x, float y, float z);
  private:
    vector<palm> palms;

};

void forehead::palmstrikesforehead(float x, float y, float z) { 
  Palm::Palm palm(x,y,z);
  palms.push_back(palm); //Exception thrown if this line is not commented out.
}
```

The code works with a vector of integer type, but not with a vector of Palm type. What I would like to do is to anonymously add Palms to the vector (as in the java: `arrayList.add(new Palm(x,y,z));`. How may that be done?

Comment: What kind of mutant has palms on his forehead?

Comment: Is the type named `Palm` or `palm`?

Comment: Facepalm? As in palm of hand going to face?

Comment: No exception is thrown! It's a compiler error. Others have provided solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class name seems to be `palm`. So you should write

```
  palm the_palm (x, y, z);
//^^^^
  palms.push_back(the_palm);
```

Or you could construct the palm in-place:

```
  palms.push_back(palm(x, y, z));
```

Comment: Or change `vector<palm> palms;` to `vector<Palm::Palm> palms;`

Comment: @crush: Unless there is a really `Palm` class in the `Palm` namespace or class, I believe that `Palm::Palm` is a mistake.

Comment: In C++11, you can construct it even more in place: `palms.emplace_back(x,y,z);`

Answer (score 0):

If `Palm` is the correct class name (you don't get a compile error), then `Palm::Palm palm(x,y,z);` should be `Palm palm(x,y,z);`

Answer (score 0):

```
class forehead {
  public:
    void palmstrikesforehead(float x, float y, float z);
  private:
    vector<Palm::Palm> palms;

};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to solve at present as we don't know what is in Palm never mind what it's called.

Assuming that Palm is your own class, there is potentially an issue with your copy-constructor. Is your class obeying the "rule of 3"?

To "anonymously add", assuming your class is called palm, you would do:

```
palms.push_back( palm(x,y,z) );
```